# How to update JSON payload when values are embedded in backslash in Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy, groovyshell, groovy-console

In Groovy I have to update values in JSON payload and make an API call. I am running into challenges while updating payload as the fields are embedded in backslash. Is there a simpler way to directly update the servers in below payload i.e update **1. JSON payload** to **2. Updated JSON payload** (updating name and host values).

**1. JSON payload:**

```
    {
    "environment": "dev",
    "config": "Create",
    "configType": "Server",
    "ServerName": "",
    "Servers": "[\\{\"name\":\"Server-test_1\",\"host\":\"test.com\",\"port\":\"443\",\"tls\":\"2-way\"}]",
    "tsHost": "",
    "tsPort": "",
    "tsSSLOption": "1-way"
    }
```

**2. Updated JSON payload:**

```
    {
    "environment": "dev",
    "config": "Update",
    "configType": "Server",
    "ServerName": "",
    "Servers": "[\\{\"name\":\"Server-test_2\",\"host\":\"test123.com\",\"port\":\"443\",\"tls\":\"2-way\"}]",
    "tsHost": "",
    "tsPort": "",
    "tsSSLOption": "1-way"
    }
```

Tried below (losing backslash in conversion process):

**Code:**

```
    def json = $/ {
    "environment": "dev",
    "config": "Create",
    "configType": "Server",
    "ServerName": "",
    "Servers": "[\\{\"name\":\"Server-test_1\",\"host\":\"test.com\",\"port\":\"443\",\"tls\":\"2-way\"}]",
    "tsHost": "",
    "tsPort": "",
    "tsSSLOption": "1-way"
    } 
/$
    def parser = new JsonSlurper()
    def jsonResp = parser.parseText(json)
    println(jsonResp.Servers)
    jsonResp.Servers.name = "Server-test_2"
    jsonResp.Servers.host = "test123.com"
```

Comment: The fields are _not_ embedded in backslash. The backslashes escape the following characters. See [Introducing JSON, string](https://www.json.org/json-en.html).

Comment: Can you post your Groovy code. Also why are there escape characters before a curly bracket?  If you post the Groovy code I will troubleshoot it for you. But to be clear the backslashes are just escape characters.  Also, is this in Jenkins or just groovy? Your tag says Jenkins

Comment: I second Chris. If this is in Jenkins in which project type is it?

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli I am using groovy script in pipeline to implement a function. (This is just groovy, sorry for the confusion). API needs data in the format posted in the payloads. Updated post with code in code section.

Comment: **Code:**

import java.io.*
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper


    def json = $/ {
    "environment": "dev",
    "config": "Create",
    "configType": "Server",
    "ServerName": "",
    "Servers": "[\\{\"name\":\"Server-test_1\",\"host\":\"test.com\",\"port\":\"443\",\"tls\":\"2-way\"}]",
    "tsHost": "",
    "tsPort": "",
    "tsSSLOption": "1-way"
    } 
/$
    def parser = new JsonSlurper()
    def jsonResp = parser.parseText(json)
    println(jsonResp.Servers)
    jsonResp.Servers.name = "Server-test_2"
    jsonResp.Servers.host = "test123.com"

Comment: @GeroldBroser,  I am using groovy script in pipeline to implement a function. (This is just groovy, sorry for the confusion).

Comment: Please add the code to your question by using the _Edit_ link below the tags under your question.

Comment: You’re having an issue because the value of the servers property is a string, not an array of json objects. You need to convert the string into an array of json objects before you can interact with it as if it were json. It has nothing to do with the escape characters. Then, depending on the API, you probably need to convert it back to a string at which point the escape characters should be managed for you. That is if I’m understanding you correctly, which I’m still not 100% sure of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Servers` is a string in your initial json - you have to parse it

```
import groovy.json.*

def json = $/ {
    "environment": "dev",
    "config": "Create",
    "configType": "Server",
    "ServerName": "",
    "Servers": "[{\"name\":\"Server-test_1\",\"host\":\"test.com\",\"port\":\"443\",\"tls\":\"2-way\"}]",
    "tsHost": "",
    "tsPort": "",
    "tsSSLOption": "1-way"
    } 
/$
def parser = new JsonSlurper()
def jsonResp = parser.parseText(json)
println(jsonResp.Servers)

def servers = parser.parseText(jsonResp.Servers)
servers[0].name="Server-test_2"
servers[0].host="test123.com"
jsonResp.Servers = JsonOutput.toJson(servers)
json = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(jsonResp))
```

Comment: To be precise (for the OP): In this answer's code `Servers` is a string that contains a definition of an [array `[...]`](https://www.json.org/json-en.html#array) that contains one JSON object `{...}` as only element. But what's the the escaped backslash in the question's code? An error?

Comment: you are right. we don't have any info where 1-st json is coming from. if it's just a static data - definitely it's typo.

Comment: Thank you @daggett. Worked with dev team and modified the payload.